# Convert a timestamp to YYYY-MM-DD with JS

Tags: javascript

In JS I have `1496102400000` how can I convert it to something more readable: `2017-05-30` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of here, You should type your title in Google, There are 1000 of solutions available.

Comment: @slackOverflow: the link is for HH:MM:SS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date except use a different constructor for Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date